# Unity3d: Accessing class from another script via GetComponent error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, null

*FIXED* I'm trying to access a class contained in another script and i get this:  "Internal_Create can only be called from the main thread". The .init function just changes some values inside the class.

I've tried to fix it by searching for answers, but i couldn't find anything helpful.

This is the main loop where the error occurs:

```
public class MainLoop : MonoBehaviour {

public float jagginess;


void Start () {
    jagginess = 0.6f;
    CMesh cmesh = GameObject.Find("GameObject").GetComponent<CMesh>();
    cmesh.init(32);

}


void Update () {

    //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {

}
```

} and the mesh class:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]

public class CMesh : MonoBehaviour {

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

        Texture2D heightMap;

        int segments;
        Vector3 scaleSegments;

        Vector3[] vertices;
        Vector3[] normals;
        Vector2[] uv;
        int[] triangles;

        Vector3 camera_position = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").GetComponent<cameraMovement>().camera_pos;

        public void init(int mesh_segments) {

            scaleSegments = new Vector3(200, 100, 200);

            segments = mesh_segments;

            initHeightMap();
        }
```

Comment: @Burdock

`using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainLoop : MonoBehaviour {
 
 public float jagginess = 0.6f;
 
 
 void Start () {
  
  CMesh cmesh = (CMesh)gameObject.GetComponent<CMesh>();
  cmesh.init(32);
  
 }
 

 void Update () {
  
  //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
 
 }
}`

Comment: It is not a good idea to post a lot of code in comments. You can always edit your post above. That being said, your class is fine. Look at my answer below, it should solve your problem.

Comment: `using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]

public class CMesh : MonoBehaviour {

  Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
  
  Texture2D heightMap;
  
  int segments;
  Vector3 scaleSegments = new Vector3(200, 100, 200);
  
  
  
  Vector3 camera_position = GameObject.Find ("Main Camera").GetComponent<cameraMovement>().camera_pos;
 
  public void init(int mesh_segments) {
   
   segments = mesh_segments;
  
   initHeightMap();
  }
  `

Comment: @FunctionR. Yes, that did solve the error. now i get another one

Comment: What is the new error?

Comment: ' you are not allowed to call this function when declaring a variable' and 'internal_create can only be called from the main thread'

Comment: On which line of code is that error happening?

Comment: CMesh..ctor () - I only get this for the first error.
 The second one says 'UnityEngine.Mesh..ctor () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/ea95e74f6e5f192d/Runtime/ExportGenerated/Editor/Graphics.cs:1255)
CMesh..ctor ()'

Comment: I've added the code to the question.

Comment: The first error was because of initialising the variable before the start function. Fixed. Now it's only the Internal_Create issue

Comment: I have commented out lines of code to get to see where exactly the error occurs. I couldn't find anything, and when i deleted all the //, it worked. Don't know, don't ask. Thanks, guys, i couldn't have done it without you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask yourself this question every time before using `GetComponent()`: **What GameObject contains the script you are looking for?**

Once you know the name of the GameObject you can do this if the Script is attached to a different Game Object:

`CMesh cmesh = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObject").GetComponent<CMesh>();`

If the script is attached to the same GameObject you can do this:

`CMesh cmesh = GetComponent<CMesh>();`

Comment: Note that this has already been addressed, the issue does not have to do with referring to this.gameObject

Comment: You have been addressing the issue incorrectly. In fact saying `this.gameObject` is redundant. My code will work for sure.

Answer (score -2):

You missed casting the component. Try :
CMesh cmesh = (CMesh) gameObject.GetComponent< CMesh >();

Before that, make sure that the script you wanna access is on the same object. Otherwise you need to get that object first then get the component:

CMesh cmesh = (CMesh) GameObject.Find("The Object Name here").GetComponent< CMesh >();

The second ones always works for me.

I hope this helped.

Cheers!

Comment: In unity, GetComponent<T>() does not need casting because it is a generic